# (psychoPy) RatingScale with letter (as opposed to number) keys

Tags: psychopy

I have a script with lots of RatingScale components, used to record 1-through-5 ratings (subjects pressed keys 1 through 5 on the keyboard).

I now need to change the script to accept five letter inputs instead of the first five numbers (i.e., the keys, Q,W,E,R,T). I would like to keep the rating-scale components in the script and just change the expected input type (letter as opposed to digits), but I did not find any options for this among RatingScale's parameters. The 'low' and 'high' parameters just accept numerical values.

Any thoughts how I can achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `respKeys` argument.

```py
visual.RatingScale(win, respKeys=['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't'])
```

It's in the [RatingScale documentation](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/ratingscale.html).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - there is a respKeys parameter that can be set, within the customised code tab of the rating scale component!